Bash printf gives strange random output?
I have this Bash script:
#!/bin/bash
foo=$'\376'
printf '%x' "'$foo"

If I run the script a few times like this:
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
./script.sh
./script.sh
./script.sh
...

the output is:
55ad
562b
5576
55f0
557d
5642
55c6
5568
55ef

Why do I get this random output? If should just print fe.
I'm using Bash GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

weird i dont get that behavior.   Got junk in the file maybe?

@BretWeinraub what version of Bash are you using?

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)

it spits out 'fffffffffffffffe' with no newline

@BretWeinraub ha that's even weirder! LC_ALL=C does seem to fix it but I don't understand why it would be random without that. That makes no sense.

Is the apostrophe inside "'$foo" a typo or this is the intention?

Although the Bash manual specifically says that its built-in printf will interpret the given argument as the ASCII value of the following character, that is not aligned with POSIX, which says: "the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote" (emphasis added).  That is, the "character" is expected to be a valid code sequence in the current locale's character encoding.  I suspect that Bash's docs may just be out of date in this regard.

@axiac: the apostrophe is intentional - see the link John Bollinger posted.

I can reproduce this problem with bash 4.4.18.

this is a bug in bash. See printf.def function asciicode() in bash4.4 from https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f/builtins/printf.def#L1242 . Function asciicode() there is responsible for converting an argument to Bash printf starting with a leading ' to " to an integer.
/* NO check is needed for garglist here. */
static intmax_t
asciicode ()
{
  register intmax_t ch;
#if defined (HANDLE_MULTIBYTE)
  wchar_t wc;
  size_t mblength, slen;
#endif
  DECLARE_MBSTATE;

#if defined (HANDLE_MULTIBYTE)
  slen = strlen (garglist->word->word+1);
  mblength = MBLEN (garglist->word->word+1, slen);
  if (mblength > 1)
    {
      mblength = mbtowc (&wc, garglist->word->word+1, slen);
      ch = wc;      /* XXX */
    }
  else
#endif
    ch = (unsigned char)garglist->word->word[1];

  garglist = garglist->next;
  return (ch);
}

When MBLEN fails, it returns -1, but because size_t is unsigned, then if (mblength > 1) suceeds and then mbtowc does no checking, assigning garbage value ch = wc.

I'm fairly sure you're seeing a memory corruption bug in Bash. The numbers that are printed out look like the top 32 bits of an executable memory address when randomized with ASLR under 64-bit Linux.
To be more specific: on 64-bit Linux, by default, executable binaries that are position independent (PIE binaries) are loaded at a random starting address between 0x0000555555554000 and 0x0000565555554000, in multiples of 0x1000. The high 32 bits of this address will therefore vary from 0x5555 to 0x5655, which matches the range of values you're seeing. (Note that the high 16 bits of this value are all zero).
To confirm this, you can add the line grep bash /proc/$$/maps | head -n 1 to your script. This should print out the base address that bash is being loaded at, and the first 4 hexadecimal digits of that base address should match the random output from printf.
Note that if you do the printf repeatedly within a single shell session, you'll always get the same output corresponding to the address in the current shell process. It's only by running the printf in a new shell process (e.g. via ./script.sh) that you get the random behaviour.

I was able to confirm the bug and my hunch with the online tester here: https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler. This runs GNU bash 4.4.20. With this script:
#!/bin/bash
foo=$'\376'
printf '%x\n' "'$foo"
grep bash /proc/$$/maps | head -n 1

I get the following output:
557a
557aa11f2000-557aa12f6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3497                       /bin/bash

which confirms that the random output from printf is the top 32 bits of a memory address inside bash.

Wow great debugging! And thanks for being friendly :-)

This appears to be a bug in Bash. Although I didn't have LC_ALL set, if I run locale it prints:
❯ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

If you change the value to this:
foo=$'\376\123'

Then it deterministically prints 563e. I suspect it is trying to interpret the value as UTF-8 and doing an out-of-bounds read, which is why it's getting random values. I'm still not quite sure where 563e comes from though.
Using LC_ALL=C fixes the issue.
